# Get comments and replies from YouTube video

Tags: c#, youtube

I want to get the first comment in the list and replies for that comment from any YouTube video. Please can anyone guide me the exact way to achieve it. Thanks

I tried YouTube API but it can give only the comments but not the reply for the comments.

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("applicationName", "developerKey", "userName", "passWord");
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId);
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
var comments = request.GetComments(video);
```

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: added my code which i tried till now